# creating a site which needs to communicate with magento database

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am currently working on (a part of) a site where people buy an item from a magento based e-commerce website. However, to use that item, they need to go to another website. Basically that "other" website is what I am working on (and doing it via codeigniter)

I dont know much about magento. the only information my website needs from the magento website is some information regarding products (id, name and status). This information will be linked to other tables, i.e the product ID may be a foreign key in a table in my database. I did a little research and was able to figure out how data is stored in the magento database.

Both websites will be on same server.

Now I have two options which I could think of to get products from the magento website into my website,

first is that I create insert,update and delete triggers for the required tables in the magento website so that when a product is added, modified or deleted, it first tries to do the same on my database, and if successful, continues to do it in the magento database.

second option is that I simply merge the two databases of my website and magento website creating a direct relation link between the tables.

Like I previously stated, I dont know much about magento. So i wanted to know which was the safer, better approach or if there was an approach I diddnt think of.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

further clarification of task:
Basically there is a magento website (lets call it "WEBSITE A") which sells "**products**". When a person buys a "product", they are basically given a "code" for that product. To use this "code", they have to go to another website which I am building using codeigniter (lets call this "WEBSITE B").

Now as you can guess, the code needs to be used in WEBSITE B, and once used it unlocks stuff for the user based upon the **product** to which the code belonged.

As you can guess, this will create a lot of links between **product** and other stuff.
**product** although created in WEBSITE A , is used in WEBSITE B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first option: Never duplicate data unless you can help it. Why couldn't you query the Magento database instead, since it's on the same server?

Your second option: Never merge databases that aren't related.

Both options are basically anti-patterns. What you should do is query the Magento database directly, or if you want to use the Magento helper functions, include Magento and use its API directly:

```
<?php
require_once 'path/to/Mage.php';

// Use Magento APIs
?>
```

Comment: basically the problem is that my website will have tables that will have fields which will be foreign keys to the magento product. and (atleast from what I understand), you cant have foreign keys in different databases

Comment: Would you be able to go back to the beginning and describe what you are trying to do in detail? My answer solves the problem given in the original question, but without more information I can't help you further.

Comment: sorry for the delay, updated main post and tried to describe as clearly as I could, hope it helps, and thanks :)

Comment: In that case, you would need to use an API to validate a coupon on your CodeIgniter project. I'm not sure if Magento already has an API for coupons, but it'd be easy enough to create if not. You definitely don't want to be responsible for syncing coupon data between two databases, or merging them.